# Redirect to another URL by scrolling with smooth animation

Tags: javascript, url, animation, redirect, scroll

I'm trying to replicate what these guys are doing [here](http://www.e-types.com)

I've set up 2 test pages so perhaps I can better explain what I'm trying to achieve.

This is the page I wanna land on - eh19.ehdsonline.com/sof-video

Then this is the page I want to go when I scroll down — eh19.ehdsonline.com/sof-home

Idea is that when you land on the "SOF-video" page — by scrolling down — I want to scroll into "SOF-home" with a smooth transition/animation.  Exact same thing as the www.e-types.com example.

Here's the code I'm trying to achieve this with, but it doesn't seem to do the job.

```
document.getElementById("content-986").onscroll = function() {
   window.location = 'http://eh19.ehdsonline.com/sof-home';
   console.log("test");
}
```

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The example application you have showed is actually not redirecting to a new page although it appears to be. It is a single page application and the URL seems to be changing.

Using the history api in HTML5 this can be done. The idea is to make calls changing the url without reloading the page. Example:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

You could load a component/div and when you scroll you can make another component/div appear instead and change the url. This is something you can easily achieve in React if you are using something like React Router.

Comment: Thanks. How would this translate though in my 2 pages I've set up? I'm pretty new to JavaScript, and the example code doesn't really ring a bell. Not to mention the React Router suggestion. I'd appreciate some help here... Thanks.